# How to Direct download from RecyclerView items(Firebase url)? Can't make it work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, download, android-download-manager

I'm fetching some Firebase files and I'm listing them with RecyclerView, I want to download one of those files when i click in a download button in the ListItem, not by redirecting to the url but direct downloading.

I've tried different kind of ways to achieve this but anything just doesn't seem to work, I've tried download-manager, AsyncTask but any of those either won't work or will crash the app, I've configured android permissions in the manifest file so the problem is not there, it's frustrating, if anyone could give me some help because I'm stuck here. Below my code

```
public class MaterialiAdapter extends RecyclerView .Adapter<MaterialiAdapter.MaterialiViewHolder>  {


Context context;
ArrayList<Upload> uploadMateriali;

public MaterialiAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Upload> u){
    context=c;
    uploadMateriali=u;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MaterialiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
     return new MaterialiViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_materiali,parent,false));
 }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MaterialiViewHolder materialiViewHolder, final int i) {
    materialiViewHolder.txtEmri.setText(uploadMateriali.get(i).getEmriMateriali());
    materialiViewHolder.txtUrl.setText(uploadMateriali.get(i).getDateMateriali());
   final String url=uploadMateriali.get(i).getUrlMateriali();
   final  String name=uploadMateriali.get(i).getEmriMateriali();
    materialiViewHolder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload(url,name);

        }
    });

}

private void startDownload(String url, String fileName) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);  // Tell on which network you want to download file.
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  // This will show notification on top when downloading the file.
    request.setTitle("Downloading a file");
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);  // Storage directory path
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uploadMateriali.size();
}

class MaterialiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView download;
    ImageView delete;
    TextView txtEmri;
    TextView txtUrl;

    public MaterialiViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDownMateriali);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDelMateriali);
        txtEmri = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMaterialiName);
        txtUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMaterialiDate);

    }
}


}
```

So the code that I currently have has a download-manager implemented, and that just won't work it will crash the app, it might be because of the context(non activity class), I don't know any more..

Logcat:

```
06-10 07:47:09.631 1119-1119/com.example.studentsapplication 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.studentsapplication, PID: 1119
java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:470)
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:460)
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:432)
    at com.example.studentsapplication.MaterialiAdapter.startDownload(MaterialiAdapter.java:68)
    at com.example.studentsapplication.MaterialiAdapter.access$000(MaterialiAdapter.java:34)
    at com.example.studentsapplication.MaterialiAdapter$1.onClick(MaterialiAdapter.java:60)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
  (ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: Can you paste the logs?

Comment: Yes, just let me execute it again!

Comment: I think the problem was with the URL i dont know why though

Comment: Exactly. There is problem in the url. Please debug and check if the url is passing in the arguments.

Comment: Yes i fixed it, it took me a day and the problem was at the setters and getters

Comment: Good. I was expecting !

Comment: I’m not able to upvote, request failed

Comment: No issues buddy